# Rails Unidentified Method Issue: undefined method `outlet_id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, migration

In my database I am trying to get a one to many relationship between outlets and articles.

I am getting the following error when that relationship is used:

```
undefined method `outlet_id' for #<Article:0x007fc353887e58>
```

Here are the models:

```
    class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :analyst 
      belongs_to :outlet
      has_and_belongs_to_many :loe
      attr_accessible :article_body, :author, :distribution, :loe, :most_important, :pubdate, :publication, :state, :submitted, :summary, :title, :url, :analyst_id, :loe_ids, :outlet_id
    end

    class Outlet < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :articles, foreign_key: :title
      attr_accessible :distribution, :name, :state, :article_ids
    end
```

Here are the schema:

```
  create_table "articles_loes", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "article_id"
    t.integer "loe_id"
  end

  create_table "loes", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "customer"
    t.integer  "article_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  add_index "loes", ["article_id"], :name => "index_loes_on_article_id"

  create_table "outlets", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "articles_id"
    t.integer  "distribution"
    t.string   "state"
    t.datetime "created_at",   :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   :null => false
  end

  add_index "outlets", ["articles_id"], :name => "index_outlets_on_articles_id"
```

And here is the chunk of the view that calls on `:outlet` :

```
  <div class="span4">
    <%= f.association :loe %>
    <%= f.association :outlet %>
  </div>
```

If anyone has any ideas I'd really appreciate them. I think I might need an index of Outlets in Article? I'm not really sure how to implement that if that is the case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have added the "articles_id" to outlets table mistakenly. You need to have outlet_id in articles table instead.

Answer (score 2):

Right now there is no way for your `Outlet` model to associate with the `articles` that it has. Once you say `belongs_to`, you need to have an `outlet_id` `column`. So you need to add an `outlet_id` (integer) column to your `Article` model and populate it with the id of the outlet they belong to. If an Article can belong to many outlets in that case you need to create a `many-to-many` relationship through a joint table.